# Prove that if $f \circ g$ is one-to-one, then $g$ if one-to-one

Tags: calculus, functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, examples-counterexamples

Let $f$ and $g$ be functions and have domain $\mathbb{R}$. I have to prove or disprove two claims:

(1) if $f \circ g$ is one-to-one, then $f$ is one-to-one

(2) if $f \circ g$ is one-to-one, then $g$ is one-to-one

For (1), could you give me an intuition as to why the statement is wrong? What counter-example can be used?

For (2), how should I prove or approach the question? I have attempted direct proof, but I couldn't link the "IF" and "THEN" part.

Comment: Right now both of your statements are exactly the same.

Comment: How is $f\circ g$ defined? $(f\circ g) (x) = f(g(x))$ or vice versa?

Comment: Sorry @NinadMunshi, I fixed the question.

Comment: @Wuestenfux yes, that's exactly it.

Comment: Regarding 2) suppose it isn’t true, i.e. that g could not be injective (1-1) yet $(f\circ g)(x)$ be injective.  But then there exist $x,y$  such that $g(x) = g(y)$. In which case $(f\circ g)(x) = (f\circ g)(y)$ creating a contradiction.  However, this doesn’t necessarily mean that g injective implies $(f\circ g)(x)$ is injective.

Answer (score 1):

The first statement is false: take $g(x)=e^x$ and $f(x)=x^2$. The $f\circ g$ is injective, but $f$ isn't.

But the second statement is true. If $f\circ g$ is injective and $x,y\in\Bbb R$ are such that $g(x)=g(y)$, then $f\bigl(g(x)\bigr)=f\bigl(g(y)\bigr)$, and therefore $x=y$. So, $g$ is indeed injective.

Comment: I see. I understood the counterexamples, but am still confused with the proof for statement (2). How do you conclude that $f(g(x)) = f(g(y))$ implies $x=y$?

Comment: From the fact that $f\circ g$ is injective.

Comment: Doesn't that only conclude $g(x) = g(y)$ but not $x=y$? Or are those two things the same?

Comment: No. Asserting that $f\circ g$ is injective means that$$(f\circ g)(x)=(f\circ g)(y)\implies x=y;$$in other words,$$f\bigl(g(x)\bigr)=f\bigl(g(y)\bigr)\implies x=y.$$